# Semantic search on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, embedding

I know PostgreSQL has trigram trigram similarity search and even indexing optimized for it (`CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON table USING gist (column gist_trgm_ops);`), which can be used directly from Django (web framework):

```
Model.objects.filter(attribute__trigram_similar=query_string)
```

But what if, instead of surface similarity, I wanted to perform semantic similarity query on database objects? (which is obviously quite different from classic trigram similarity).

Good example would be Google's [universal sentence encoder](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/modules/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2), where I would convert all strings into 512 dimensional embedding vectors (using the library) and perform query by calculating normalized dot product (cosine similarity) and yield the object with highest similarity (or perhaps n amount objects with similarity `>=0.50`).

Simplest thing to do is to iterate (at the framework level) on the database objects, but this is highly inefficient (especially if database is large), therefore I would rather to find a way where I could perform query on the database level (and perhaps if possible set up optimal indexing for semantic search?).

---

What would be the best way to perform this custom similarity search on the database of pre-vectorized objects?

What if, I get dot product of all objects in the pre-vectorized database manually?

Thank you!

Comment: The trigram indexing is not comparable.  Google is creating *numeric* matrices along different dimensions.  The more apt comparison would be geo-spatial extensions or explicit matrix extensions (I don't think the latter exist, though).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Of course, I'm not trying to compare trigram similarity search to the advanced search function that main Google search system might have. But one of their systems (such as the game [Semantris](https://research.google.com/semantris/) or the searching system [Talk to books](https://books.google.com/talktobooks/)) utilizes universal sentence encoder as well.  What I linked, utilizes deep averaging neural network (taking vector average of embedding treebank tokenized string, passing it through >=1 hidden layers and applying linear classification on output layer).

Comment: @GordonLinoff For semantic search, they also use optimized cosine similarity, converting it to angular distance: 1-arccos(cosinesim(x, y))/pi

Comment: . . That sounds really sophisticated.  I would just start with principal components.  In any case, I'm pretty sure the representation is a matrix of weights, rather than a sequence of codes, but I might be misinterpreting the limited information I have.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Indeed, good thing is, that they already have pre-defined library for that purpose. According to them, inner product of their embedding vectors is already enough to great semantic similarity accuracy. What if I performed database-level query (using normal inner product, or something more advanced) on those vectorized objects?

Comment: . . It would work (assuming that you change the vectors to Postgres types or introduce appropriate functions to operate on them).  It is unlikely that the code would scale, though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Inner product performed between 512 dimensional vectors is very fast, but converting input to that will also take time. I guess testing is the optimal method, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query for PostgreSQL.

You can replace the ARRAY[1,2,3] with the embeddings for the text you can to search for. The length must be the same of the documents.embeddings field.
For example, if you used OpenAI ada model to calculate embeddings you must use the same for the search query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cosine_similarity(a float[], b float[]) RETURNS float AS $$
  DECLARE
      dot_product float = 0;
      norm_a float = 0;
      norm_b float = 0;
  BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. array_length(a, 1)
      LOOP
          dot_product = dot_product + a[i] * b[i];
          norm_a = norm_a + a[i] * a[i];
          norm_b = norm_b + b[i] * b[i];
      END LOOP;
      RETURN dot_product / (sqrt(norm_a) * sqrt(norm_b));
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


  SELECT *, cosine_similarity(documents.embeddings, ARRAY[1,2,3]) as cosine_similarity
   FROM documents
  ORDER BY cosine_similarity DESC
```